# Python extract data from txt file and ignore the headers

Tags: python, extract

I have a txt file that presents nodes and edges between nodes. The node-part contains some additional information. The file looks like this:

```
@nodes
label    characteristic A    characteristic B
1        vfn                 5
2        ksdv                625
3        asn                 0

@edges
1 3
2 3
```

I can extract the information if I have one file for the nodes and one for the edges without headers without a problem, but how can I extract the information if the file looks like the example? Since the skript has to work for all node-edge-files in this format I cannot just cut out certain lines, I need to somehow spot the @-symbol and cut along that line. In addition to that I need to cut out the node header with the characteristics while the edge section does not have a header.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You just want to extract two text portions?

Comment: You should try to improve your question to get a useful answer. First, show what code you have already tried (and how it failed) - or at least what do you plan to do with the data. The title needs change, too - you don't want to "ignore" the headers - they actually tell you what kind of data follows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
file = open(“testfile.txt”, “r”) 
for line in file:
    if line[:1] != "@":
    print line or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("nodes.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if '@' in line:
            # skip the header if you want here
            continue
        data = line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

**It this what are you looking for?**

The result are two list: nodes, edges

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open("nodes-edges.txt") as g:
    data = g.read().replace('@nodes\n', '').split('\n')[1:]

    is_node = True
    nodes = []
    edges = []

    for item in data:
        if item == '@edges':
            item = ''
            is_node = False

        if item:
            list_elements = [element for element in item.split(' ') if element != '' ]

            if is_node:
                nodes.append(list_elements)
            else:
                edges.append(list_elements)

    print('nodes: ', nodes)
    print('edges: ', edges)
```